# How to delete the corrupted Cassandra keyspace

Tags: cassandra

I tried to drop the Cassanda (1.2.6) keyspace by issuing "DROP KEYSPACE" CQL command. The command hanged.

I cannot access anymore this keyspace, cannot create a new one by the same name and cannot drop it again.

What would be the recovery tactic? Can I simply remove the folder from "data" dir with the offended keyspace? What would be correct way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: "The command hanged": hanged, or started running and took longer than your patience? How long did you leave it?

Comment: I left it for about 20 minutes. The keyspace is pretty much empty with less than 100 records in total.

Comment: Thanks Raedwald, I disabled the auto_snapshot but there is no improvement. 
Moreover I am asking here how I can delete this keyspace as I am unable to do so.

Comment: What do you get if you type `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE "your_keyspace"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try scrubing the keyspace first, from the command line:

```
nodetool scrub name_of_my_keyspace
```

That will clear intermediate tables which are probably corrupt. After that you can drop the keyspace or just continue to use it.

This happens a lot when you run tests on a computer where Cassandra crashes once in a while because of an out of memory. I have had that problem more than once.